# Load Data during Splash Screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I need to know is there any way to perform a task during splash screen is visible in flutter. I know how to add splash screen in flutter but I don't know how to perform background operations during splash screen is visible. I can't find anything on the internet, please help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, yes you can. The `main()` function can actually be tagged as `async`, so you can do whatever you need to do before running `runApp(...)` in the `main()` method body, **even asynchronously**. This way, the splash screen will be shown until your asynchronous result is retrieved, before calling `runApp(...)`. For example:

```
Future<void> main() async {

// Do whatever you need to do here
final home = await setHomeWidgetDependingOnLoginStatus();

return runApp(MyApp(home: home));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the await statement block the runApp() method here? Other than that I think your answer is mostly correct.

Comment: Isn't that what the poster asked for? He wants to run code while showing a splash screen. I think we can assume he wants to resume the app as soon as that code is done which will be when the await will finish.

Comment: I thought he wanted to start a task while the splash screen is visible. Not start AND finish a task while the splash screen is visible. I think the distinction might still be relevant for some readers as the initial question is, in my opinion, a little ambiguous on this aspect. But I can understand your interpretation now, and your answer is correct.

Comment: Also, my splash screen is the `home`.

Answer (score 1):

The animated_splash_screen package does this worderfully. add it to your `pubspec.yml`

```
    animated_splash_screen: ^1.1.0
```

```
AnimatedSplashScreen.withScreenFunction(
  splash: 'images/splash.png',
  screenFunction: () async{

  // Your code here

    return MainScreen();
  },
  splashTransition: SplashTransition.rotationTransition,
  pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.scale,
)
```

This will load and hold you splash screen until your function is complete.

Your function has to return a widget, in this case is your home screen. This also allows for dynamic routing depending on your data eg, is user logged in.