# is it possible to run initialisation code before native splash screen is removed by flutter engine in flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await, initialization, splash-screen

I want run initialisations of the application and fetch some data async in flutter before app starts and while native splash screen is active.

I want to start the app after all initialisations are complete and then i want to remove native splash screen and start flutter application.

Basically i want to fetch shared preferences and run init code snippets and path_provider code before starting user interaction and while native splash screen is running after flutter engine is loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58615545/load-data-during-splash-screen-in-flutter ? Seems like you want to delay the flash screen disappearing so you can run initialisation code first.

Answer (score 1):

Not during the actual Native splashscreen. But you can create a screen that looks identical to the native splashscreen, do your stuff there, and then navigate once you are done.